# ggplot2 geom_area producing unexpected output

Tags: r, ggplot2

While attempting to solve my [question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601100/plotting-a-bedgraph-in-ggplot2), I thought of wrangling the data so that the datapoints can be correctly plotted without needing to resort to `geom_step`, which does not fill the area under the bedgraph plot.

I generated the following code, which should produce a shaded bedgraph plot, similar to the [output produced by the `plotBedgraph` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2itRu.png).

```
wrangleBdg<-function(dfInput){
    starts<-subset(dfInput,select=c("start","value"))
    ends<-subset(dfInput,select=c("end","value"))
    colnames(ends) <- c("start", "value")
    dataWrite <- rbind(data.frame(starts, index = 1:nrow(starts)), data.frame(ends, index = 1:nrow(ends)))
    dataWrite <- dataWrite[order(dataWrite$index), c("start", "value")]
    dataPlot<-ggplot(dataWrite,aes(x=start,y=value))+geom_area() + xlim(chromstart, chromend)
    return(dataPlot)
}
p3<-wrangleBdg(df)
print(p3)
```

However, it instead produces the garbled output shown below. Note the value above 2, where the data's maximum height is 1.377:

[image]

Changing the `geom_area` function to `geom_line` removes the garbling, however we are back to square one with an unshaded plot.

[image]

The data used to generate the plot is shown below:

```
 chrom start   end   value
 chr13     0   882 0.00000
 chr13   882   885 0.02968
 chr13   885   886 0.00000
 chr13   886   887 0.02968
 chr13   887   888 0.00000
 chr13   888   890 0.02968
 chr13   890   892 0.00000
 chr13   892   894 0.09667
 chr13   894   908 0.00000
 chr13   908   909 0.02968
 chr13   909   923 0.00000
 chr13   923   926 0.02968
 chr13   926   927 0.09667
 chr13   927   928 0.02968
 chr13   928   933 0.09667
 chr13   933 42032 0.00000
 chr13 42032 42035 0.52301
 chr13 42035 42056 0.45043
 chr13 42056 42059 0.52301
 chr13 42059 42063 0.45043
 chr13 42063 42065 0.38020
 chr13 42065 42075 0.29973
 chr13 42075 42078 0.15975
 chr13 42078 42079 0.23307
 chr13 42079 42080 0.29973
 chr13 42080 42086 0.38020
 chr13 42086 42087 1.28112
 chr13 42087 42114 1.18640
 chr13 42114 42116 1.28112
 chr13 42116 42123 1.37702
 chr13 42123 42127 1.28112
 chr13 42127 42128 1.18640
 chr13 42128 42139 1.09943
 chr13 42139 42142 1.07272
 chr13 42142 42144 1.09943
 chr13 42144 42147 1.18640
 chr13 42147 42148 0.29973
 chr13 42148 42150 1.18640
 chr13 42150 42152 1.28112
 chr13 42152 42162 0.38020
 chr13 42162 42167 0.29973
 chr13 42167 42168 0.23307
 chr13 42168 42171 0.29973
 chr13 42171 42173 0.38020
 chr13 42173 42181 0.29973
 chr13 42181 42186 0.45043
 chr13 42186 42187 0.52301
 chr13 42187 43000 0.00000
```

Comment: Looking at your data, this chart makes sense... You have some non-zero data between 882 and 933 and then 0.0000 between 933 and 42032 and then some non-zero data from 42032 to 42187. That's what I'm seeing being plotted: two spikes. Can you clarify what kind of output you're expecting to see?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten A filled version of the second graph. I'm not sure how the chart "makes sense", since the lines are all over the place.

Comment: Gotcha. I suspect that the spikes are so thin that geom_area is resulting in some graphical artifacting for some reason.

Comment: You should clarify what your actual question is here... you want to know why geom_area isn't working or...?

Comment: @nicolaskruchten That and a way to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `position = "identity"` to your `geom_area` command:

```
#original:
dataPlot<-ggplot(dataWrite,aes(x=start,y=value))+geom_area() + xlim(chromstart, chromend)

#modified version:
dataPlot<-ggplot(dataWrite,aes(x=start,y=value))+geom_area(position = "identity") + xlim(chromstart, chromend)
```

**Explanation:**

Take a look at your dataWrite dataframe. Except for the first & last row, you have 2 different numbers in the value column for each number in the start column.

```
> head(dataWrite %>% arrange(start))
  start   value
1     0 0.00000
2   882 0.00000
3   882 0.02968
4   885 0.02968
5   885 0.00000
6   886 0.00000
```

Thus when you plot `geom_area` with `x = start, y = value`, its default position adjustment stacks one value on top of the other. The largest value observed in your original plot (2.658) is a result of the two values at start = 42116 (1.281 and 1.377) added together.